# How to remove svn folders over FTP on Windows hosting

Tags: windows, svn, ftp, directory, delete-directory

I've accidentally copied a large part of a folder tree from my SVN working copy to my shared Windows web host via FTP.

The site is now littered with .svn directories and and I need some way of cleaning them. The only access I have to the server is via FTP, or by running a script on the server.

Does any one have a script which can be run remotely to remove the files over FTP from my development machine (any language Windows/Linux is fine) or a script in ASP, ASP.net or PHP I can run directly on the Windows server to remove these directories?

Comment: You said that any language Windows/Linux is fine, and I guess bash fits in. Please state clearly what you expect in your questions and do not downvote instead.

Comment: @pajton - I believe I clearly stated my host was running Windows on the first line of my question. Further down I mention a solution could either be run directly on the server in a number of languages installed or over FTP from any configuration - so a shell script which runs on Linux but can interact with the windows host over FTP is fine, but a shell script which expects to run on the same machine isn't. I have edited my question to hopefully make this clearer.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

`for /f “tokens=* delims=” %%i in (’dir /s /b /a:d *svn’) do ( rd /s /q “%%i” )`

taken from http://www.axelscript.com/2008/03/11/delete-all-svn-files-in-windows

also in regard to your statement further above try running it in php with the following

```
<?php
echo `for /f “tokens=* delims=” %%i in (’dir /s /b /a:d *svn’) do ( rd /s /q “%%i” )`;
?>
```

Comment: Just about to try this - do you mean exec() rather than echo though?

Comment: try both, i prefer echo because you "theoretically see the output the shell returns"

Comment: Just got round to trying this and I can't seem to get it to work. I replaced the smart quotes with ' and " as described in the link but it just prints the string. When I use exec() or system() I see no effect at all.